# HttpClient : doing something when the api returns nothing

Tags: angular

After calling a post(), I would want to do something (here calling the url /getEmployees), if my api returns something it works fine, but if my api returns nothing the navigate() is not fired.
My question : how doing something when the api returns nothing ?

EmployeeComponent

```
validateEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.addEmployee(this.employee).
      subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/getEmployees'])),
      error => {
        this.error = error.message;
      };
  }
}
```

EmployeeService

```
addEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.post(this.employeeSrvUrl + 'addEmployee', JSON.stringify(employee));
}
```

Comment: Can you share your server side code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the subscribe API
[image]

That's telling you that there are 3 parts to a subscribe..
next:
error:
complete: //aka finally

So if you want to navigate irrespective of errors...

```
validateEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.addEmployee(this.employee).
      subscribe(()      => { console.log('success') },
                (error) => { this.error = error.message },
                ()      => { this.router.navigate(['/getEmployees']) }
               );
}
```

Comment: i think he is not telling about the finally but just about if the data returned is nothing like null, in that case a `if case ` might be sufficient i guess ?

Comment: @RahulSingh  Quote from op: "if my api returns nothing the navigate() is not fired"

Comment: ya in that case it might me null also also sorry i just overlooked that , i was curious to check if only a if can do the job or not ?

Comment: @RahulSingh This is a post not a get too. With a get you'd possibly be assigning an empty result like [] as record[]  in the error part. for things like a 404 response.

Comment: Thanks JGFMK, it works fine ! The only condition is that the api must returns null